# Unwrapping error while using listAll method of Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'd like to fetch all pictures in my bucket of Firebase Storage by using "listAll" method. But I got unwrapping error on using "results" variable in for statement as below;

```
    func fetchAllPictures(bucket: String) { 
        let pictureRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(bucket) 
        pictureRef.listAll { (results, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error while uploading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            for item in results.items {
                print(item)
                item.getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024) { ( data , error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error while uploading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    } else {
                        guard let data = data else { return }
                        let fetchedImage = UIImage(data: data?) ?? UIImage(named: "Main_Home")
                        self.$pictures.append(fetchedImage)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would very appreciate if anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

I did try forced wrapping but it caused another error such as number of argument in closure
I just let go of the unwrapping error

Comment: you can add guard let results = results else { return } before the for loop

Comment: It didn't work and it makes another error on closure with "Contextual closure type '(Result<StorageListResult, any Error>) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body" comment. And it was added with "Value of type 'Result<StorageListResult, any Error>' has no member 'items'" on the loop additionally

Comment: maybe "(results, error)" should be "(result, error)" -------> "result" not "results" https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files

Comment: Can you use one of the argument, if the error still returned, for example (result, error) in -> result in

Comment: Thanks for caring answers, but any of them doesn't work. I used both of your suggestions but it still has number-of-argument-error and no matter with "result" and "results" both...

Comment: I think you should update you package, it works for me.